# compilation terminated. exit status 1 error compiling for board arduino/genuino uno

Tags: arduino-uno

hi i have done this code for my uno R3 and i cant upload it 
any suggestions

```
#include"DHT.h"
#define DHTPIN 8
#define DHTTYPE DHT11
DHT dht( DHTPIN,DHTTYPE);
const int ledPin=13
int piesoPin=9
void setup(){
  serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(ledPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(piezoPin,OUTPUT);
  delay(5000);
}
void loop(){
  int t=dht.readTemperature();
  int h=dht.readHumidity();
  Serial.print(t);
  if(t>26){
    digitalWrite(ledPin,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(piezopin,HIGH);
    {TONE(9,3047,400);
    delay(1000);
    noTone(8);
    delay(100);
    }
    delay(1000);
    Serial.print("ON T=");
  }
  else(digitalWrite(piezoPin,LOW);
  digitalWrite(LEDpIN,LOW);
  Serial.print("OFF,T=");
  }}
```

Comment: Michel Keijzers gave the answer, but I noticed a few others things. The dht.readTemperature returns a float, you convert it to an integer. The adafruit dht library makes a shortcut in the signal: https://github.com/adafruit/DHT-sensor-library/issues/48

Comment: I am pretty sure the compile told you more than that.

Answer (score 2):

Two errors I see is a typo and missing semicolons.

```
const int ledPin=13
int piesoPin=9
```

Should be

```
const int ledPin=13;
int piezoPin=9;
```

Also I see a unnecessary { and } but this cannot cause a compilation error.

Check the delays, when the temperature is higher than 26 degrees you have more delay than when not, maybe this is intended, maybe not.

However, you probably typed over the code, so maybe there are more errors, please add the exact error text and line in your question.